# iphone icon won't show up in itunes

Tags: itunes

I upgraded iTunes and now my iPhone won't show up in it. I have uninstalled iTunes, reinstored it and still nothing. I go to file, click on devices and sync etc is not highlighted. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you see the device in Device Manager (Windows) or in System Report (Mac)?

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port? A different cable?  I know you think the symptom is upgrading iTunes, and it may be, but eliminate the other possibilities too.

Comment: I can't see the iPhone in the device manager on my computer. I have an iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered here for a different problem, but maybe relevant to you -
[iPhone 6 won't connect to Windows 7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216215/iphone-6-wont-connect-to-windows-7)