# iPhone 6 won't connect to Windows 7

Tags: windows, iphone

My computer was dead for 3 months and when I bought a new battery, I tried to plug my iPhone 6 and nothing pops up. It doesn't connect at all not even to charge like it would before. I updated my laptop and iTunes, I verified the Apple mobile device support, I restarted the Apple mobile device, I checked the unspecified and nothing, I went to the device manager and there's nothing about Apple on there, I need to upload all my stuff to my computer but I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control Panel / System and Security / System.
2. In the System window check the System type for wether your operating system is 32-bit or 64 bit type.
3. Make sure your iTunes is 32 or 64 bit as per your operating system.

If this is ok then -

1. Type services.msc and click Ok.
2. Make sure Apple Mobile Device Services is set to Automatic.

If this is ok then - 
I would suggest you search - "Apple Mobile Device Driver" and install them.